# how to print request and response from rest assured to extentreport html

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, extentreports, extent

I am using extent report with testng and rest assured. default print stream for RestAssured is System.out, but System.out statements are not showed in extent html report. 
How to show system.out.print statement in extent reports ??
if not how to show response and request in extentreports- i need to change the LogConfig, but i am not sure how to change.

Answer (score 0):

**public static ExtentTest test;
test.log(Status.INFO, response.prettyPrint());** use these two lines in your @Test you will get the response in your extent report.
Note: The **test variable** should be present in the extent report class.